# get data after population NodeJs MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, population

this is my schema
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ri7x.png)

i have population query like this

```
 let population = [{model: Customer, path: 'customer'}, {model: Role, path: 'role', select: 'user', populate: {model: User, path: 'user'}}]
```

and the result of this query is like this

```
 "data": [
            {
                "isactive": false,
                "created_at": "2020-01-20T07:57:36.251Z",
                "_id": "5e255e7fe560893f0c30f9ce",
                "code": "4",
                "name": "DISTRIBUTOR 1",
                "contact": "ronald",
                "phone": 812117562425,
                "email": "info@test.com",
                "tipe": "A",
                "__v": 0,
                "customer": null,
                "role": {
                    "_id": "5e255e96e560693f1c30f2cf",
                    "distributor_id": "5e255e2fe522083f0c30f9ce",
                    "user": {
                        "isactive": false,
                        "last_login": "2020-01-21T02:15:55.073Z",
                        "superUser": false,
                        "_id": "5e255fb6e560893f0c30f9d0",
                        "role_id": "5e255e96e560893f0c30f9cf",
                        "name": "yogi",
                        "description": "Admin1"
```

my question is, how can i get only the user data from each role, in one distributor?

Comment: Please include your related `schemas` in your question

Comment: hi Fahad, i have included my related schema in my question.

Comment: On which collection you want to query ?

Comment: i want to query Distributor collection and get all user data in one distributor.

Comment: But your `distributor` collection don't have any direct relationship with `user` so you can't get `user` data on behalf of `distributor` using populate

Comment: ok fahad, thank you for helping my  issues